# Como usar o Vagrant ou o Packer em ambiente de produção?

Tags: vagrant

Estou começando a estudar o Vagrant junto ao Chef e já percebi que ele é ótimo para ambiente de desenvolvimento, facilitando muito a vida quando se é bem configurado, porém ele não monta um ambiente seguro o suficiente para ser reproduzido em produção, pelo menos eu não encontrei formas de deixa-lo seguro em produção ainda. O que quero saber é se é possível e o q devo fazer para manter 100% de semelhança entre meus ambientes de desenvolvimento, teste e produção e ainda desfrutar das facilidades do Vagrant e Chef?

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que configurar o box para deixa-lo igual a produção, dai o box vc configura como linux mesmo, no arquivo Vagrantfile não sei se vai dar pra colocar todas config. Mas seja mais especifico com o que você quer fazer.

Comment: é que no meu servidor de produção eu usao senha no linux e no mysql, e dou as permissoes necessarias. No caso da senha do linux eu posso troca-la por ssh. No vagrant daria pra eu associar minha chave ssh? pq o vagrant cria uma pasta compartilhada com o hospedeiro e é ae que esta a falha de segurança que impede o uso em produção. Estou correto em afirmar isso?

Comment: Tava pensando aqui, qual é o proposito exato de usar Vagrant na produção? Voces montam muitos servidores por dia?

Comment: nao, sao poucos, o vagrant em producao serviria para duas coisas creio eu. 1 - manter a igualdade do server de desenvovimento, testes e producao e manter a evolucao destes servidores sempre alinha. tudo isso ao alcance de um vagrant up

Comment: Eu não consegui ficar satisfeito com o Vagrant para produção. Hoje eu uso vbox, a mesma imagem, faço deploy no servidor local e produção. Faço isso a anos e sinceramente, não mudaria isso por nada.

Comment: vbox seria o virtual box? Se eu entendi bem vc cria uma VM no virtual box na mão mesmo e depois a usa tanto em dev como em prod?

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente, eu acho que o uso do vagrant e mais para homomlogação, tendo em vista a questão da segurança, organização  (particionamento de disco) da so, hardering  e o uso da virtualização (bare metal) como o provider do virtualbox. Eu como sysadmin, uso mais para gerar um simulação do cenário de produção, rodando via vagrant  3-6 vms com diferentes sistemas operacionais como está em produção, de acordo com o projeto. Aí posso alterar algum quesito, seja na interconexão, ou versões e etc, que sei que vai roda em produção, e para fazer o deploy de fato em produção, uso o docker. Assim, na so em homologação pelo vagrant, usamos o docker que isola somente a aplicação ( o filé ) e jogar para o servidor em produção sem nenhuma problema de compatibilidade.